# set open_files_limit

Tags: mysql, configuration

When I set open_files_limit = 16k in both:
/etc/security/limits.conf 
and
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
ulimit -n
16344
```

but in mysql:

```
show variables like 'open_files_limit';
open_files_limit: 4096
```

So how does mysql calculate open_files_limit. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: would you have to restart mysql once to take effect?

Comment: I did and tried restarting the server.

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify it as `open_files_limit` or `open-files-limit` in my.cnf? In config file it should be `open-files-limit`.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: You can try running `lsof` on MySQL’s pid, piped to `wc -l`.

Option 2: `ll /proc/<mysql-pid>/fs/`

These will give you the list of open files (including sockets, etc.; everything is a file in Unix/Linux).

The open files limit can be checked on the `mysql-client` using `show global varaibles like '%files%'` and then `set global variable open_files_limit=<some-larger-number>`

Be careful about this, since the number from `ulimit -n` is a total for the shell for all processes, and you don’t want to put it too high.

If you see this number slowly increasing, you probably want to check your code: there are dangling references.

Answer (score 0):

check limits for user mysql:

`limits -e -U mysql`

`ulimit -a` - show limits for your user

If limits correct && you use Percona MYSQL then need activate limits in start script.

For example in FreeBSD: `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server`
find string: `${mysql_limits="NO"}` and replace `NO` -> `YES`

PS. 2Janne Pikkarainen in my config my.cnf: `open_files_limit = 8192`