# MySQL open files limit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-10.04, ulimit

This question is similar to [set open_files_limit](https://serverfault.com/questions/184915/set-open-files-limit), but there was no good answer.

I need to increase my `table_open_cache`, but first I need to increase the `open_files_limit`.  I set the option in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
open-files-limit = 8192
```

This worked fine in my previous install (Ubuntu 8.04), but now in Ubuntu 10.04, when I start the server up, `open_files_limit` is reported to be 1710.  That seems like a pretty random number for the limit to be clipped to.

Anyway, I tried getting around it by adding a line like this in `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
mysql   hard   nofile   8192
```

I also tried adding this to the pre-start script in mysql's upstart config (`/etc/init/mysql.conf`):

```
ulimit -n 8192
```

Obviously neither of those things worked.  So where is the hoop that has been added between Ubuntu 8.04 and 10.04 through which I must jump in order to actually increase the open files limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it - there are no extra hoops, it's just the mysql config that lied!  I had put the `open-files-limit` line in the `[mysqld_safe]` section, but it seems that section is no longer used. Moving all config options to `[mysqld]`...

Comment: Seems that mysqld_safe is not needed anymore in Ubuntu, probably due to upstart introduction.